# Javascript: Compare top-level domain

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

i would like to compare two link and know their the top-level domain are the same.
This is required by Google AdWords because the final url and the ad url shown may have the same top-level domain.

For example i need

```
link1 = 'adwords.google.com';
link2 = 'www.google.com';
if(compare(link1,link2)){
    console.log('OK');
}
```

how can I write the function compare()?

Comment: That's nice but, what is your question? What have you tried, what are your errors?

Comment: All you need to do is split each url and check if the last element is the same.

Comment: I'm asking how can I write the function compare()?